# prop.test display the confidence interval in percentage terms instead of decimal in R?

Tags: r, testing, confidence-interval

I am wondering if there is a way to change the output settings of the prop.test function in R so that it displays the confidence interval already in percentage terms instead of a decimal? For example, I am trying to find the 95% confidence interval for the proportion of immigrants in the West with diabetes. Here is my code and the output:

```
    sum(Immigrant_West$DIABETES)= 8, nrow(Immigrant_West)=144
prop.test(x=sum(Immigrant_West$DIABETES),n=nrow(Immigrant_West),conf.level = .95,correct=TRUE)

    > 1-sample proportions test with continuity correction
    data:  sum(Immigrant_West$DIABETES) out of nrow(Immigrant_West), null probability 0.5 
   X-squared = 112, df = 1, p-value <2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true p is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.02606 0.11017
sample estimates:
      p 
0.05556
```

So is there a way to change the confidence interval output to show [2.606%, 11.017%] instead of as decimals? Thank you!

Comment: Easy enough to write your own wrapper func.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will probably be simpler:

```
prp.out <- prop.test(x=8, n=144, conf.level=.95, correct=TRUE)
prp.out$conf.int <- prp.out$conf.int * 100
prp.out
# 
#   1-sample proportions test with continuity correction
# 
# data:  8 out of 144, null probability 0.5
# X-squared = 112.01, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
# alternative hypothesis: true p is not equal to 0.5
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#   2.606172 11.016593
# sample estimates:
#          p 
# 0.05555556
```

Comment: Note that the estimate is still a proportion so you might want to add `prp.out$estimate <- prp.out$estimate * 100`.

Answer (score 0):

Not easily.  The print format is controlled by the `print.htest()` function, which is documented in `?print.htest`: it doesn't seem to offer any options other than the number of digits and the prefix for the "method" component.

If you want, you can hack the function yourself. (More details to follow, maybe; dump `stats:::print.htest` to a file, then edit it, then `source()` it.

As suggested by @CarlWitthoft:

```
p <- prop.test(x=8,n=144)
str(p) ## see what's there
p$estimate <- p$estimate*100
p$conf.int <- p$conf.int*100
```

Comment: I'd recommend just writing a wrapper `myprop.test` which mucks with the output list element(s) , rather than risking breaking something that matters in the original function code.

Comment: Ok that sounds like a good idea Carl. Thank you! How would you recommend setting up that wrapper? I tried something like this but am not sure..   my.prop.test <- function(x) { 
  return(prop.test(x,conf.level = conf.level*(100)))
  }